# How to traverse back to root vertex in gremlin in one single query

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using Gremlin in amazon-neptune. I have vertex **user, country, order**

I have edge 'lives_in' from user to country ,edge 'purchased' from user to order, edge 'delivered' from order to country

Goal : Find top most country which purchases most orders to foreign country rather than live_in country in descending order

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("user").outE('purchased').inV().hasLabel("order"). 
......1> outE("delivered").inV().hasLabel("country").
......2> has('name').neq(outE('lives_in').inV().hasLabel("country").values()).
......3> groupCount().by(values)
```

**I am not able to traverse back to root vertex from step neq(outE("lives_in"))**

I am getting the same results after removing the last has step

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("user").outE('purchased').inV().hasLabel("order").
......1> outE("delivered").inV().hasLabel("country")
```

This means my last has step is not executing. 

Result sample - {v[country_GB]=38,v[country_NZ]=6,v[country_AU]=3}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always helpful to include a small sample graph like this in your question:

```
g.addV('user').as('u1').
  addV('user').as('u2').
  addV('order').as('o1').
  addV('order').as('o2').
  addV('order').as('o3').
  addV('order').as('o4').
  addV('order').as('o5').
  addV('order').as('o6').
  addV('country').property('name','usa').as('usa').
  addV('country').property('name','candada').as('can').
  addV('country').property('name','mexico').as('mex').
  addE('lives_in').from('u1').to('usa').
  addE('lives_in').from('u2').to('mex').
  addE('purchased').from('u1').to('o1'). 
  addE('purchased').from('u1').to('o2').
  addE('purchased').from('u1').to('o3').
  addE('purchased').from('u1').to('o4').
  addE('purchased').from('u2').to('o5').
  addE('purchased').from('u2').to('o6').
  addE('delivered').from('o1').to('usa').
  addE('delivered').from('o2').to('mex').
  addE('delivered').from('o3').to('mex').
  addE('delivered').from('o4').to('can').
  addE('delivered').from('o5').to('mex').
  addE('delivered').from('o6').to('can').iterate()
```

Based on that, here's one way you might do this:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("user").as('u').
......1>   out('lives_in').hasLabel("country").as('c'). 
......2>   select('u').
......3>   out('purchased').hasLabel("order").
......4>   out("delivered").hasLabel("country").
......5>   where(neq('c')).
......6>   groupCount().
......7>     by('name')
==>[mexico:2,candada:2]
```

A few things to note:

1. Simplify `inE().outV()` and `outE().inV()` to just `in()` and `out()` respectively if you aren't doing anything with the edge.
2. At the line marked 1, the "lives_in" country vertex is labelled for later comparison against the "delivered" countries at line 5
3. The result excludes order labelled "o1" and the order labelled "o5" as both of those orders originated in the country to which they were shipped.

Comment: This is very helpful but ,when i follow point 1 from the notes i get "Exception processing a script on request".  This query worked for me  -- g.V().hasLabel("user").as('u').out('lives_in').hasLabel("country").as('c').select('u').outE('purchased').inV().outE('delivered').inV().hasLabel("country").where(neq('c')).groupCount().by('name') . Question 1 - Does it consume more memory if i use inE().outV() type syntax. Question 2-  What can i add to sort result in descending order as sort() dint wort for me. Thanks

Comment: I can't imagine why that change would matter...maybe something with neptune? I don't think it will consume more memory, but it's unnecessary. In fact, I think there is a `TraversalStrategy` that will re-write it to the shortened form anyway if you choose to write the long form - i guess the strategy execution would cost you something, but I doubt it is measurable. To sort just add `order().by(values))`

Comment: After running several queries , i noted that it is problem with neptune if you don't use outE() instead of out() . I want to sort groupCount result so adding order().by(values)) at the end doesn't  work for me .

Comment: that stinks. i wonder why neptune does that. also, i assumed you were trying to sort the counts from the groupCount(). is that not what you wanted? order() step should sort maps (the result of groupCount()) just fine - see examples here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#order-step

Comment: I used the groupCount().order() , groupCount().order().by(incr) but getting the same result again and again. I am looking for result like this [mexico:3,candada:2,usa:1].Many Thanks :-)

Comment: should be `groupCount().order().by(values, decr)`

Comment: I tried groupCount().order().by(values, decr) , groupCount().order().by(keys, decr), groupCount().order().by(count(), decr) . Moreover i found groupCount().cap().orderMap(T.decr).map().toList() from google gremlin forum but none of this is working.

Comment: sorry - should be `order(local).by(values,decr)` - the "local" signifies that you want the ordering to occur on the current object in the stream (which is your single map) rather than the stream itself.